# Is it possible to generate glyphs for the Linux terminal on the fly?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, terminal, glyph

For example, Impulse Tracker for DOS was a nice music production app that was among the first to create a smooth mouse using glyphs generated on the fly in the characters located near the current position of the mouse. ([Read here for a better description of what I mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA-compatible_text_mode#Cursor)).

So, I'm just wondering if that can be done in Linux terminals (e.g. the tty1-6 terminals or Gnome Terminal). Is it possible?

(EDIT: Should I post this on unix.stackexchange.com instead?)

Comment: I think this will go better if you just go with a basic graphics environment. Running a simple x11+awesome with one window is possible in almost all machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as the terminal itself (and not the application) usually sets the font being used, I don't think this is possible. For the tty1-6 terminals, you could use a framebuffer to accomplish this, if you were that dedicated to the idea. With a terminal emulator on a desktop environment, I do not believe this is possible.

Would GPM accomplish what you're looking for, with a lot less hassle?

[GPM Link 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPM_%28software%29)

[GPM Link 2](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_gpm.htm)

Comment: That's cool, I got gpm working. However, I'd still like to know if It's possible change the glyphs for a specific character at row Y column X. Or can I change the font that gets outputted for a single character?

Comment: As far as I know, it isn't, and if my response answers your question, could you please mark it with the checkbox?